# Grammatical word for feeling related

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a specific word for charaterstic of sentences which are not objective and are somewhat related to feelings , there was some "be" property in sentence.i mean there was a sentence example and in that sentence "be"was used instead of another word.I had read this word in one of the comments,I am getting really restless to know this word .

Comment: T Christ - it was your comment !

Comment: "Not objective" = ***subjective***. "Related to feelings" = ***emotive***. Either or both may be applicable in any given context.

Comment: I feel the word started with "s".. And it was in a grammatical context .

Comment: Are you thinking of [subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)?

Comment: Yes !!! Subjunctive, I want to delete the question so please delete the answers .

Comment: @Argot: If *subjunctive* really was the word you were looking for I have to say you probably don't understand what it means.

Comment: You should have started by [browsing tchrist's comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist?tab=activity). and asking in chat, for which you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Yeah , I really don't understand the word , it is really " abstract " and I tried searching for tchrist's comment but did not not know we could browse for comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) is used to express "necessity, desire, purpose, suggestion and similar ideas", which could be interpreted as "sentences relating to feelings".

Comment: Quite weird word and quite abstract .

Comment: Subjunctive is **not a tense**. In fact it says just that in the first three words of your very own link.

Comment: Gah, you're right. What I get for not paying attention when I type. Fixed.

Comment: It's also very rare in English. And, in addition, the overwhelming majority of sentences that express "necessity, desire, purpose, suggestion and similar ideas" are **not** subjunctive, so it's not even a good label for the category.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't disagree. But, whether it's an appropriate word or not, it *was* the one the OP was thinking of, which is about as close to a correct answer as we'll get on this one, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Tendential [having or showing a definite tendency, bias, or purpose: a tendentious novel.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tendential)

Answer (score 0):

You could be thinking of "biased" or "subjective".

Comment: Sorry , not even close . Though it is my mistake of not able to explain properly.